# Toolbar height too low

Tags: android, xamarin

I use a `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` in my Xamarin Android project. In my Fragments I include it with the following line:

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar_actionbar" />
```

After that it is display correctly:

[image]

I tried this aswell on a Activity with the same code. But here is display like that:

[image]

The code in the Activity and the Fragment who sets the Toolbar is in both cases:

```
SetSupportActionBar(FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar));
SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Do I have to set the size manually to a fix value or whats wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to making it look correctly is to use `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your layout.

You can find a full sample here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/blob/master/XPlatformMenus/XPlatformMenus.Droid/Resources/layout/activity_main.axml#L9